# Using token from Simple authentication Token in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token, simple-authentication

I am using Simple Authentication token for my APIs in Rails.

As given in the documentation: https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication:

In my User model, I have added the following line: 
    acts_as_token_authenticatable

Whenever I login or logout, I am able to get and change the athentication tokens as expected.

What I don't understand is, what is the use of the below line.

acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

I have a controller called ProfilesController in which I have added this line. Whether or not I add this line in the controller makes no difference. I am able to call methods in the similar way as I use without adding it.

Can you please explain me what this does?

Comment: Have you added this line in the `ApplicationController`?

Comment: No. In my ProfilesController I am using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that gem says this behaviour of incorrect or no credentials is [configurable](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication#integration-with-other-authentication-and-authorization-methods).

> What happens when a request is provided with no credentials or
>   incorrect credentials is highly configurable

For denying access you have to set the `fallback`

If you have devise set it to `fallback: :devise` or `fallback: :exception` in your [`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication#allow-controllers-to-handle-token-authentication)

Comment: Thank you. I was just getting confused on how 'acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for' is actually working but I have got the view now. Thanks!